# ADF: how to remove values set to the view criteria

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am using Jdev 11g for development.

Now the issue is: I cannot update the values of the view criteria every time I have new values for it.

For example, there's a view criterion VC which contains 2 criteria name and age. I have set the values for name and execute SQL to get results.

Now I need to reset the view criteria and set new values to name or age.

I use the below code to reset the view criteria:

```
vo.removeViewCriteria(viewCriteriaName);
ViewCriteria vc= vo.getViewCriteria(viewCriteriaName);
vc.reset();

//update the view criteria
ViewCriteriaRow vcr = (ViewCriteriaRow)vc.first();
ViewCriteriaItem vci = vcRow.getCriteriaItem(attributeName);
vcItem.setOperator(SearchServiceConstants.IN);

//get the values here
vci.setValues(values);
vcr.setConjunction(vcRow.VC_CONJ_AND);

vo.applyViewCriteria(vc, true);
vo.executeQuery();
```

But still there's one bind variable in the view criteria which affects the SQL results.

What I want is a clean view criteria which does not have any bind data to it.

Can any one help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood  the question correctly your are asking on h**ow to apply a view criteria to a View Object while removing all previous setted view criteria values**.

In your use case the previous view criteria isn't remove because of the boolean value you are passing in the *vo.applyViewCriteria(vc, true);*

The second parameter boolean value is set to allow you to keep or remove the previously setted View criteria.

see : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e10653/oracle/jbo/ViewObject.html#applyViewCriteria(oracle.jbo.ViewCriteria,%20boolean)

> Applied the view criteria to this view object. If bAppend is true view
>   criteria is appended to the list of already applied view criteria. If
>   bAppend is false the applied view criteria list is cleared prior to
>   applying the passed view criteria. Parameters: criteria - view
>   criteria to be applied bAppend - flag to indicate if the applied view
>   criteria list needs to be cleared before applying the view criteria.

In your case you just need the two following lines in your java function :

```
vo.applyViewCriteria(vc, false);
vo.executeQuery();
```

For more informations, refer to the doc or the following tutorial : https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-apply-a-viewcriteria-programmatically-in-adf/

Comment: I tried the code but still faced the same issue. The values set for the view criteria still exist if they've been set before.

Comment: This should not, are you sure you're not setting the value once more ?

Comment: Seems applyViewCriteria(vc, false) clears of the existing list of applied view criterias and only applies the current one, while in my case there's just one view criteria and I just want to clear the previous items in the view criteria.

Comment: Can you add to your question a screenshot of your view criteria? Are you using bind variables to set the values? If so i'll write another answer on how to clear the previous values of the view criteria.

Comment: I've added the details of how I update the view criteria in the question. Pls review.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
vo.setApplyViewCriteriaName(null);
vo.executeQuery();
```

Then set your new criteria and bind variables. Always worked for me in the past